# Convert CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer Sparse Matrices into Separate Pandas Dataframe Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

**Question:** What is the best way to convert sparse matrices resulting from sklearn's CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer into Pandas DataFrame columns with a separate row for each bigram and its corresponding frequency and tf-idf score?

**Pipeline:** Bring in text data from a SQL DB, split text into bigrams and calculate the frequency per document and the tf-idf per bigram per document, load the results back into the SQL DB.

**Current State:**

Two columns of data are brought in (`number`, `text`). `text` is cleaned to produce a third column `cleanText`:

```
   number                               text              cleanText
0     123            The farmer plants grain    farmer plants grain
1     234  The farmer and his son go fishing  farmer son go fishing
2     345            The fisher catches tuna    fisher catches tuna
```

This DataFrame is fed into sklearn's feature extraction:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
dt_mat = cv.fit_transform(data.cleanText)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf_mat = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(dt_mat)
```

Then the matrices are fed back into the original DataFrame after converting them to an array:

```
data['frequency'] = list(dt_mat.toarray())
data['tfidf_score']=list(tfidf_mat.toarray())
```

Output:

```
   number                               text              cleanText  \
0     123            The farmer plants grain    farmer plants grain   
1     234  The farmer and his son go fishing  farmer son go fishing   
2     345            The fisher catches tuna    fisher catches tuna   

               frequency                                        tfidf_score  

0  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  [0.0, 0.707106781187, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7071067...  
1  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]  [0.0, 0.0, 0.57735026919, 0.0, 0.57735026919, ...  
2  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]  [0.707106781187, 0.0, 0.0, 0.707106781187, 0.0...
```

**Problems:**

1. The feature names (i.e. bigrams) are not in the DataFrame
2. The `frequency` and `tfidf_score` are not on separate lines for each bigram

**Desired Output:**

```
       number                    bigram         frequency      tfidf_score
0     123            farmer plants                 1              0.70  
0     123            plants grain                  1              0.56
1     234            farmer son                    1              0.72
1     234            son go                        1              0.63
1     234            go fishing                    1              0.34
2     345            fisher catches                1              0.43
2     345            catches tuna                  1              0.43
```

I managed to get one of the numeric columns assigned to separate rows of the DataFrame with this code:

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
rows = []
_ = data.apply(lambda row: [rows.append([row['number'], nn]) 
                         for nn in row.tfidf_score], axis=1)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['number', 'tfidf_score'])
```

Output:

```
    number  tfidf_score
0      123     0.000000
1      123     0.707107
2      123     0.000000
3      123     0.000000
4      123     0.000000
5      123     0.707107
6      123     0.000000
7      234     0.000000
8      234     0.000000
9      234     0.577350
10     234     0.000000
11     234     0.577350
12     234     0.000000
13     234     0.577350
14     345     0.707107
15     345     0.000000
16     345     0.000000
17     345     0.707107
18     345     0.000000
19     345     0.000000
20     345     0.000000
```

However, I am unsure how to do this for both numeric columns, and this doesn't bring in the bigrams (feature names) themselves. Also, this method requires an array (which is why I converted the sparse matrices to arrays in the first place), and I would like to avoid this if possible due to performance issues and the fact that I would then have to strip the meaningless rows.

Any insight is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much for taking the time to read this question - I apologize for the length. Please let me know if there's anything I can do to improve the question or clarify my process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bigram names can be captured using `CountVectorizer`'s [`get_feature_names()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.get_feature_names). From there it's just a series of `melt` and `merge` operations:

```
print(data)

   number                               text              cleanText
0     123            The farmer plants grain    farmer plants grain
1     234  The farmer and his son go fishing  farmer son go fishing
2     345            The fisher catches tuna    fisher catches tuna

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
dt_mat = cv.fit_transform(data.cleanText)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf_mat = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(dt_mat)
```

The `CountVectorizer` feature names are, in this case, the bigrams:

```
print(cv.get_feature_names())

[u'catches tuna',
 u'farmer plants',
 u'farmer son',
 u'fisher catches',
 u'go fishing',
 u'plants grain',
 u'son go']
```

`CountVectorizer.fit_transform()` returns a sparse matrix.  We can convert it to a dense representation, wrap it in a `DataFrame`, and then tack on the feature names as columns:

```
bigrams = pd.DataFrame(dt_mat.todense(), index=data.index, columns=cv.get_feature_names())
bigrams['number'] = data.number
print(bigrams)

   catches tuna  farmer plants  farmer son  fisher catches  go fishing  \
0             0              1           0               0           0   
1             0              0           1               0           1   
2             1              0           0               1           0   

   plants grain  son go  number  
0             1       0     123  
1             0       1     234  
2             0       0     345
```

To go from wide to long format, use [`melt()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html).
Then restrict the results to bigram matches ([`query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is useful here):

```
bigrams_long = (pd.melt(bigrams.reset_index(), 
                       id_vars=['index','number'],
                       value_name='bigram_ct')
                 .query('bigram_ct > 0')
                 .sort_values(['index','number']))

    index  number        variable  bigram_ct
3       0     123   farmer plants          1
15      0     123    plants grain          1
7       1     234      farmer son          1
13      1     234      go fishing          1
19      1     234          son go          1
2       2     345    catches tuna          1
11      2     345  fisher catches          1
```

Now repeat the process for `tfidf`:

```
tfidf = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_mat.todense(), index=data.index, columns=cv.get_feature_names())
tfidf['number'] = data.number

tfidf_long = pd.melt(tfidf.reset_index(), 
                     id_vars=['index','number'], 
                     value_name='tfidf').query('tfidf > 0')
```

Finally, merge `bigrams` and `tfidf`:

```
fulldf = (bigrams_long.merge(tfidf_long, 
                             on=['index','number','variable'])
                      .set_index('index'))

       number        variable  bigram_ct     tfidf
index                                             
0         123   farmer plants          1  0.707107
0         123    plants grain          1  0.707107
1         234      farmer son          1  0.577350
1         234      go fishing          1  0.577350
1         234          son go          1  0.577350
2         345    catches tuna          1  0.707107
2         345  fisher catches          1  0.707107
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this certainly gets everything into a tidy DF! The problem is, everything is mismatched, and the `number` has been separated from the bigrams (i.e. random pairings of bigrams and `number`. There are also, curiously, a few null `number`s now (there are none in the original data).

Comment: It appears to be happening immediately after densifying the CountVectorizer output and creating the dataframe with `get_feature_names` and `number`. It seems like maybe because the `number` column is simply added with no way to determine which bigrams it should match up to?

Comment: The nulls are throwing it off. Everything before the first null matches up, everything after doesn't. Why would nulls be happening? I am already filtering out rows that only have one word (i.e not eligible for a bigram).

Comment: The code in my answer is tested on your example data.  `number` and `bigrams` have the same indices in your example - each row in `bigrams` is not a bigram instance, but refers to a row in `data`.  That's why we can just add on `data.number`.  It's only in going from wide to long format that rows change from `text` to `text`-`bigram` pairs.   Can you confirm that my answer works on the 3-line example data you posted?  If there are edge cases or exceptions, such as missing values, please update your post to include a representative sample dataset that demonstrates the problems you're seeing.

Comment: I'd add `index=df.index` when calling `pd.DataFrame(dt_mat.todense(), ...)` and also for `tfidf_mat`

Comment: That extra tweak worked, thank you! And thank you, Andrew for your original, detailed answer. Now I am facing an issue with it running out of memory when I try to run it on 10,000 + records. I'm assuming the dense array being created is too large.

Comment: Great!  I updated my answer to include the explicit `index` declaration.  Thanks @MaxU.