# Python Access Labels of Sklearn CountVectorizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Here is my df after cleaning:

```
    number  summary             cleanSummary
0   1-123   he loves ice cream  love ice cream
1   1-234   she loves ice       love ice
2   1-345   i hate avocado      hate avocado
3   1-123   i like skim milk    like skim milk
```

As you can see, there are two records that have the same `number`. Now I'll create and fit the vectorizer.

```
cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", ngram_range=(1,1), analyzer='word')
cv.fit(df['cleanSummary'])
```

Now I'll transform.

```
freq = cv.transform(df['cleanSummary'])
```

Now if I take a look at `freq`...

```
freq = sum(freq).toarray()[0]
freq = pd.DataFrame(freq, columns=['frequency'])
freq

    frequency
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   1
5   2
6   1
7   1
```

...there doesn't seem to be a logical way to access the original `number`. I have tried methods of looping through each row, but this runs into problems because of the potential for multiple summaries per `number`. A loop using a grouped df...

```
def extractFeatures(groupedDF, textCol):
    features = pd.DataFrame()
    for id, group in groupedDF:
           freq = cv.transform(group[textCol])
           freq = sum(freq).toarray()[0]
           freq = pd.DataFrame(freq, columns=['frequency'])
           dfinner = pd.DataFrame(cv.get_feature_names(), columns=['ngram'])
           dfinner['number'] = id
           dfinner = dfinner.join(freq)
           features = features.append(dfinner)
    return features
```

...works, but the performance is terrible (i.e. 12 hours to run through 45,000 documents with one sentence lengths).

If I change

```
freq = sum(freq).toarray()[0]
```

to

```
freq = freq.toarray()
```

I get an array of frequencies for each ngram for each document. This is good, but then it doesn't allow me to push that array of lists into a dataframe. And I still wouldn't be able to access `nunmber`.

How do I access the original labels `number` for each ngram without looping over a grouped df? My desired result is:

```
number    ngram    frequency
1-123     love     1
1-123     ice      1
1-123     cream    1
1-234     love     1
1-234     ice      1
1-345     hate     1 
1-345     avocado  1
1-123     like     1  
1-123     skim     1 
1-123     milk     1
```

**Edit:** this is somewhat of a revisit to this question:[Convert CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer Sparse Matrices into Separate Pandas Dataframe Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957663/convert-countvectorizer-and-tfidftransformer-sparse-matrices-into-separate-panda). However, after implementing the method described in that answer, I face memory issues for a large corpus, so it doesn't seem scalable.

Comment: why the downvote? i provided a clear example and question.

Comment: so you're using the CV from scikit-learn?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
freq = cv.fit_transform(df.cleanSummary)
dtm = pd.DataFrame(freq.toarray(), columns=cv.get_feature_names(), index=df.number).stack()
dtm[dtm > 0]

number         
1-123   cream      1
        ice        1
        love       1
1-234   ice        1
        love       1
1-345   avocado    1
        hate       1
1-123   like       1
        milk       1
        skim       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This still causes performance issues (i.e. runs out of memory). Thank you, though!

Comment: You're welcome!  Sorry to hear that you're running out of memory.  Does this answer your question, `How do I access the original labels number for each ngram without looping over a grouped df?`?  Based on your computing setup and corpus size, performance may be an issue even when using only native Pandas and Sci-kit methods, as this answer does.  You might try breaking down the components and benchmarking to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: it does, thank you - just accepted it! i worked around the memory issues by converting the sparse matrices from `fit_transform` with `tocoo` from `scipy`. Then just joined back to the original df to get the labels.